# Dealing with conflicting namespaces in R (same function names in different packages): reset precedence of a package namespace

Tags: r, package

The name conflicts between namespaces from different packages in `R` can be dangerous, and the use of `package::function` is unfortunately not generalized in `R`...

Isn't there a function that can reset the precedence of a package namespace over all the others currently loaded? 
Surely we can `detach` and then reload the package, but isn't there any other, more practical (one-command) way?

Because I often end up with many packages and name conflicts in my R sessions, I use the following function to do that:

```
set_precedence <- function(pckg) {
  pckg <- deparse(substitute(pckg))
  detach(paste("package", pckg, sep = ":"), unload=TRUE, character.only=TRUE)
  library(pckg, character.only=TRUE)
}
# Example
set_precedence(dplyr)
```

No built-in way to achieve this in a single command? 
Or a way that doesn't imply `detach`ing and reloading the package, in case it is heavy to load, and working directly on namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the `conflicted` package.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that do not reload the package and work directly on the environments/namespaces.
Just replace your `library()` call with `attachNamespace()`:

```
set_precedence <- function(pkg) {
  detach(paste0("package:", pkg), character.only = TRUE)
  attachNamespace(pkg)
}

set_precedence('utils')
# now utils is in pos #2 in `search()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the package name with a double colon: `<package>::<function>()`

For instance:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data=data, ggplot2::aes(x=x)) +
    ggplot2::geom_histogram()
```

More typing, but I feel so much less anxious using R now that I have found this.